# Why is Auth0 failing with a "Failed Silent Auth"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I’ve setup (React) auth0 apps twice & i’m experiencing the same issue on both.

I login, it authenticates, i refresh the page and it errors with “login_required”.

I also get a window alert (“could not get a new token”). Then i have to login again.

In Auth0's logs, it says a Failed Silent Auth has occurred.

Nearest i can get to any explanation of that is a post about “Allowed Web Origins”. For ref: mine is set to exactly “http://localhost:3000”.

I am refreshing the page when on “http://localhost:3000/home”.

Trying to figure out what's going wrong, I did some logging in the `Auth.js` class and `accessToken`, `idToken` and `expiresAt` are all being set correctly. As is localStorage’s `isLoggedIn` value.

When `isAuthenticated` is called (when it first correctly logs in), `expiresAt` is given a `Date.now` value correctly. But when i refresh it, it zeros, which flips `isAuthenticated` to false, which i guess bounces me out/alerts the logout error above ^

What am i doing wrong here? I'm not sure I expected a starter/example repo to have errors like this.